# Difference Between online and offline payment

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal

What is the key difference between offline and online payment method in Magento 2?

How they work and how we can decide that the payment method should be offline or online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Online (immediate) :-** our system forwards the payment request without delay directly to the acquirer. The acquirer’s response is
>   immediately available but due to the communication between our system
>   and the acquirer, the process time is slightly longer.
>
> Online refund perform actual refunds refunds through payment gateway. If payment is only authorized then void() is done, and if payment is captured then refund() is done.
>
> **Offline (deferred processing) :-** our system verifies that the payment data are complete and correct, and then stores the information
>   and processes the payment later on (maximum 4 hours). This reduces
>   response time and allows the payments to be input faster.
>
> Offline simple creates credit memo but no payment gateway integration happens.

Comment: credit memo means?

Comment: credit is  document that shows the amount that is due the customer for a full or partial refund

Comment: what is refund in magento2 its mean we refund to customer or take back our product?

Comment: The amount can be applied toward a purchase, or refunded to the customer.

Answer (score -1):

**Online Payments** : module implements the payment methods which require interaction with a payment gateway, these methods are the following:

- Paypal
- Braintree
- Amazon pay
- Klarna
- Authorized.net

**Offline Payments** module implements the payment methods which do not require interaction with a payment gateway (so called offline methods). These methods are the following:

- Bank transfer
- Cash on delivery
- Check / Money Order
- Purchase order

**Source:** 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/mrg/ce/OfflinePayments.html